# Probability : permutation or choose

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

A club has $18$ members.

(a) How many ways are there to choose four members of the club to serve on an executive committee?
Solution: $\binom{18}{4} = 3060$

(b) How many ways are there to choose a president, vice president, secretary, and treasurer of the club, where no person can hold more than one office?
Solution: $P(18,4)=18 \cdot 17 \cdot 16 \cdot 15=73,440$

- Sometimes, I am confused when to pick up the permutation (P) or the choose. Correct me if i am wrong but,
- When the order matters $\to$ choose
- When the order does not matter $\to$ permutation

Comment: Other way 'round and you're good!

Comment: Go for understanding, not slogans.

Comment: Type `$\binom{n}{k}$` to obtain $\binom{n}{k}$.  Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.  Also, you are not calculating a probability here.  Problems of enumeration should be tagged combinatorics.

Answer (score 1):

> (a) How many ways are there to choose four members of the club to serve on an executive committee?
>
> Solution: $\binom {18}4=3060$

You are *selecting* four from eigteen members.

If you are counting ways to *select* items, that is a count of **combinations**.   Combinations are not distinguished by ordering. (Order is *not* important.)

- $\binom n r$ or $^n\mathrm C_r$ counts combinations of $r$ elements selected from a set of $n$
  $${^n\mathrm C_r}= \dfrac{n!}{r!\cdot (n-r)!}$$

---

> (b) How many ways are there to choose a president, vice president, secretary, and treasurer of the club, where no person can hold more than one office?
>
> Solution: $P(18,4)=18⋅17⋅16⋅15=73,440$

You are *selecting* and *arranging* four from eighteen members into four specific positions.

If you are counting ways to *select and arrange* items, that is a count of **permutations**.   Permutations are distinguished by ordering. (Order is important!)

- $P(n,r)$ or $^n\mathrm P_r$ counts permutations of arrangements for $r$ elements selected from a set of $n$.

  $${^n\mathrm P_r}= \dfrac{n!}{(n-r)!}$$
- ${^n\mathrm P_r}={^n\mathrm C_r}\cdot r!$